# numpy.genfromtxt give nan for complex numbers with minus signs?

Tags: python, numpy, nan, genfromtxt

I have some complex numbers in a file, written by `np.savetxt()`:

```
(8.67272e-09+-1.64817e-07j)
(2.31263e-08+1.11916e-07j)
(9.73642e-08+-7.98195e-08j)
(1.05448e-07+7.00151e-08j)
```

This is in a file "test.txt".
when I use `np.genfromtxt('test.txt', dtype=complex), I get:

```
                nan +0.00000000e+00j,
     2.31263000e-08 +1.11916000e-07j,
                nan +0.00000000e+00j,
     1.05448000e-07 +7.00151000e-08j,
```

Is this a bug, or is there something I can do to avoid getting `nan` from negative numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug that has been reported on the numpy github repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7895).  The problem is that `savetxt` writes a string that includes an extraneuous `'+'` when the imaginary part is negative.  The `'+'` is extraneous from the Python point of view:

```
In [95]: complex('1+-2j')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-56afbb08ca8f> in <module>()
----> 1 complex('1+-2j')

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

Note that `1+-2j` is a valid Python *expression*.  This suggests using a converter in `genfromtxt` that evaluates the expression.

For example, here's a complex array `a`:

```
In [109]: a
Out[109]: array([1.0-1.j , 2.0+2.5j, 1.0-3.j , 4.5+0.j ])
```

Save `a` to `foo.txt`:

```
In [110]: np.savetxt('foo.txt', a, fmt='%.2e')

In [111]: !cat foo.txt
 (1.00e+00+-1.00e+00j)
 (2.00e+00+2.50e+00j)
 (1.00e+00+-3.00e+00j)
 (4.50e+00+0.00e+00j)
```

Read the data back using `genfromtxt`.  For the converter, I'll use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
In [112]: import ast

In [113]: np.genfromtxt('foo.txt', dtype=np.complex128, converters={0: lambda s: ast.literal_eval(s.decode())})
Out[113]: array([1.0-1.j , 2.0+2.5j, 1.0-3.j , 4.5+0.j ])
```

Alternatively, you could use a converter that replaces occurrences of `'+-'` with `'-'`:

```
In [117]: np.genfromtxt('foo.txt', dtype=np.complex128, converters={0: lambda s: complex(s.decode().replace('+-', '-'))})
Out[117]: array([1.0-1.j , 2.0+2.5j, 1.0-3.j , 4.5+0.j ])
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This workaround seems to only work for one column? For my case I actually have an indefinite number of columns. At the same time, you can change the string format in np.savetxt(), but for complex you either do '%.4e' which cause the problem, or write format for every column. Again, I have an indefinite number of columns. I guess FML then.